# HTML 5 File load image as background-image

Tags: jquery, image, file, html, background-image

is it possible to load an image via the HTML 5 File API and make it a css background-image using javascript / jquery? If it's possible, how is it done?

Comment: Maybe convert the loaded data to a data uri. That can be used as background-image URL. See examples here: http://sveinbjorn.org/dataurls_css

Comment: That really helped! Thanks a lot. I will post how I did it as soon as possible, but thanks to reputation restrictions I can't do it for the next 5 houres

Answer (score 6):

dronus gave me a great answer to this question by posting this link in the comment section:
[sveinbjorn.org/dataurls_css](http://sveinbjorn.org/dataurls_css)

You simple have to do the following to use the image data for a css background image:
This will save the src data of your image after you create a new  and fill 
and fill it with data using the FileReader()

```
var imgFileData = $('#image').attr('src')
```

Now you simply have to take this var and set it as the background-image url

```
$('#yourDiv).css({'background-image':'url(' + imgFileData + ')'});
$('#image').hide(); //optional
```

Read the link to get a better understanding what is happening here, and thanks again to dronus