# Pre load CSS sprite Images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-sprites

I want to Pre-load two sprites images with jquery or JavaScript, These sprites image doesn't shows until page is fully loaded. i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647305/preload-background-image) ,[this](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/), [this](http://chipsandtv.com/articles/jquery-image-preload) and many more, but none of them works for me. However a simple CSS HTML based solution works.
But I have many pages so I cannot use CSS HTML solution, Rather I want use some jquery solution so as to work in one single .js file that all page has access.

CSS Html based solution that works.

```
    <div id="preload">
    <img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout.png'/>
    <img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout2.png'/>
    </div>

    <style>
    #preload{ display: none;}
    </style>
```

As this CSS HTML based solution is working, i implemented it using jQuery like this but it is not working.

```
        $(window).load(function(){

        $("<div/>", {
          "id": "preload",
          "css": { "display" : "none"},
        }).prependTo("body");
        $("<img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout.png'/>").appendTo("#preload");
        $("<img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout2.png'/>").appendTo("#preload");

        });
```

Please suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, for me this code works, although I do not have the sprites..., but FF tries to load them.
But maybe use $(function () {...}) instead of $(window).load()...

Comment: using `$(function () {...})` doesn't work as it fire on document ready state.

Comment: Why? Then you can perfectly insert something to the body so that it is loaded...

Comment: And maybe $(window).load doesnt work because there are some issues with it and it is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/  
Anyway, I do not know what your problem is because this code is perfectly working for me... What do you mean exactly with "that doesnt work for me"

Comment: means layout sprite images didn't load first.

Comment: Well, obviously it didnt load first, because you start loading when loading the rest of the page is done... The you could do the following: create a script file with the body of your .load handler (the content of the function), and include it immediately after the body tag...

Comment: i have a script file placed in head section in which above jquery code is placed, are you suggesting that i shoud move it to body section.

Comment: Yes, but you should remove the event callback, just the body of the function... $("<div/>", {
          "id": "preload",
          "css": { "display" : "none"},
        }).prependTo("body");
        $("<img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout.png'/>").appendTo("#preload");
        $("<img src='_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout2.png'/>").appendTo("#preload");

Comment: Hm, I cannot imagine why everything which I and the other solutions you have posted suggest is not working. Please specify exactly what the difference of the JS and the plain HTML-CSS is. And with exactly I mean you should describe the behaviour of your page which is relevant for that.

Comment: As i described above if i use CSS HTML based solution, my top navagation and category images(layout2.png) load before page shows up. If i use jquery solution top navagation and category images loads after the page shows up. i.e normally loading from css.

Comment: And how do you notice that? e.g. is there a short delay when first displaying the sprites?

Comment: yes with css-html no delay top navigation and category comes up with images. with jquery it takes some time for images to come.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15455/discussion-between-tall-boy-and-derwaldschrat)

Answer (score 2):

For batch image preloading:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //preload images: set path, enter image names
    var path = '../images/';
    var images = [
        'my_image.png',
        'my_image2.png'
        ];

    for (image in images) {
        new Image().src = path + images[image];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why that difficult ?!?

just do:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        new Image().src = '_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout.png';
        new Image().src = '_ls-global/images/layout-images/layout2.png';
    });
</script>
```

that does the trick. NO need for any markup.